# Text-to-speech send as the "virtual mic"

Tags: audio-recording, text-to-speech

first of all - I'm disabled person and I can not talk.

I'm searching a way to make my life a bit easier.

Is there a way to find some text-to-speech software and set its output as a virtual mic? I mean, I'd like to be able to write something and person who I am talking with for example on Skype or on the Messenger would hear this? I'm not sure how to achieve it.. can you guys help me?

I've found some text to speech app called Apex Text to Speech and it reads the text - ok. But how I can set it as my input device? I think i could capture all windows sounds but then the person I speak with would hear himself twice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set audio endpoint devices application specific (programmatically)](https://superuser.com/questions/1348988/set-audio-endpoint-devices-application-specific-programmatically)

Comment: No, this question is not related to the specified theme. The theme you mentioned discuss about simple assignment of audio endpoints to applications, while this question needs an application-to-application audio transport solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a digital audio loopback tool like [Virtual Audio Cable](https://vac.muzychenko.net) (I'm the developer). Just configure Apex Text to Speech to send its audio output to "Line 1" (if there is no way to specify output device explicitly, set "Line 1" as the default playback device), and select "Line 1" as the audio input in Skype instead of the microphone.

If trial version will be suitable for your needs, please contact me directly for a free license.